# Generate HTML Table from Curl Response

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, html-table

My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
//set Header
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//set POST variables
$url = 'https://api.example.com';
$fields = array([
    'Type' => "Free",
    'Value' => "UK1234"
]);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/json', 'APIKEY: aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
//save response to variable $result
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

This returns the following array:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "ABC123",
        "Type": "Free",
        "Sector": "Software",
        "Name": "Beta A"
      },
      {
        "id": "ABC124",
        "Type": "Free",
        "Sector": "Software",
        "Name": "Beta B"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to output specific objects, for instance *id*, *Sector*, *Name*. These would be the table headers. I tried a basic **for loop** but it didn't work:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++) {
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<td>' . $result[0]['data'][$i]['id'] . '</td>');
  echo('<td>' . $result[0]['data'][$i]['Sector'] . '</td>');
  echo('<td>' . $result[0]['data'][$i]['Name'] . '</td>');
  echo('</tr>');
}
```

I can't figure out why. I also tried removing `[0]`, and this is what I get:

```
<tr><td>[</td><td>[</td><td>[</td></tr>
```

The reason it shows html is due to `'Content-Type: application/json'`.

Anything simpler than a **for loop**? This `"data":[...]` is giving me troubles and I have a hard time choosing the correct path to the object I want.

Comment: Have you used `json_decode`?

Comment: @Scopey yes I actually did, but the result is still the same

Comment: whats the output of this command: `print_r(json_decode($result));exit;`. It should print the data returned by the curl command

Comment: @Scopey you were both correct. See my update. This question can be deleted as it is ambiguous or perhaps straight forward.

Comment: @NadirLatif same for you!

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
//decode response in order to access objects
$data = json_decode($result, true);
```

Also, the correct approach for the loop should be as follows:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data[0]["data"]);$i++) {
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[0]['data'][$i]['id'] . '</td>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[0]['data'][$i]['Sector'] . '</td>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[0]['data'][$i]['Name'] . '</td>');
  echo('</tr>');
}
```

Comment: Actually using `foreach($data[0]['data'] as $item)` would be more efficient here, or at least put the count in the first section of the for loop: `for($i=0, $count = count($data[0]['data']); $i<$count; $i++)`